# SevOne - High Frequency Poller retrieval/creation via API

Tags: rest, soap

Is it possible to view the high frequency poller objects via the REST api or SOAP api? Been poking around the api but with no success in retrieving that information.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Poked around and found that there is indeed an endpoint exposed via the SevOne SOAP API:

- polling_highfrequency_getObjects
- polling_highfrequency_addObject
- polling_highfrequency_removeObject

It was also observed that the SevOne REST API has yet to expose an endpoint for this.